# create a cumulative count of adjacent repetitions in a column

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to create a cumulative count of adjacent repetitions in a column. For instance the desired output for `repeat_n` in the code below should be c(1,2,3,1,2,1,2), but instead I am getting c(1,2,2,1,2,1,2). Perhaps because `case_when()` is vectorized, `case_when()` evaluates all values simultaneously rather sequentially evaluating the updated values. How should I avoid this problem?

```
library(dplyr)

tibble(x = c(1,1,1,0,0,1,1)) %>% 
  mutate(
    repeat_n = 1, 
    repeat_n = 
      case_when(
        x == lag(x) ~ lag(repeat_n) + 1,
        TRUE ~ repeat_n
      )
  )
```

Comment: @RonakShah am was a typo that has since been repaired

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `rleid` in `data.table` to create groups and then create a column with row number for each group.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, repeat_n := seq_len(.N), rleid(x)]
df
#   x repeat_n
#1: 1        1
#2: 1        2
#3: 1        3
#4: 0        1
#5: 0        2
#6: 1        1
#7: 1        2
```

For the same purpose, we can use `lag` in `dplyr` to create groups.

```
df %>%
  group_by(gr = cumsum(x != lag(x, default = first(x)))) %>%
  mutate(repeat_n = row_number())
```

---

Another alternative in `data.table` as suggested by @chinsoon12

```
setDT(df)[, repeat_n := rowid(rleid(x))]
```

This does not require formation of any groups and should be faster.

---

In base R, we can use `rle` with `sequence`

```
with(rle(df$x), sequence(lengths))
#[1] 1 2 3 1 2 1 2
```

**data**

```
df <- tibble(x = c(1,1,1,0,0,1,1))
```